# Outgoing emails from China based VPS rejected or marked as spam

Tags: email, email-server, spam-filter

I just switched email service provider from Google apps to a VPS with a Hong Kong host. Now I find a huge part of all outgoing emails ending up in spam boxes and in some cases getting totally rejected by receiving servers. I've set up SPF records, rDNS and all of that, but it seems a lot of European clients' mail servers are just not fond of mail from HK.

We're based in China so everything even remotely Googlesque works terrible which is why I switched in the first place. Also, we have a lot of people coming in for short term projects so I ideally wouldn't want to go back to the $5/month per user solution.

I'm not sure what would be a good solution, any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a VPS in a different country with less of a "reputation".

Much of China's IP blocks, especially Hong Kong, will be treated with extreme suspicion for the forseeable future. There's nothing you can do about it. While I laud you for setting up SPF and rDNS, it's trying to make a silk purse out of a sow's ear.

Also, check your IP at [MXToolbox's blacklist checking tool](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) and you'll probably find the marks of a checkered past. It's unlikely that your provider takes any care to scrub IP addresses clean between users.

**EDIT:**

To find empirical evidence of what is going on, seek to coordinate with those organizations that have an email infrastructure that rejects your messages. Seek to learn from their systems concerning what is the greatest reason(s) for your email being SCL'd so high.